# HBase connection exception

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I try to run HBase in a Pseudo-Distributed mode. But it doesn't work after I set hbase-site.xml.

Each time I try to run a command inside hbase shell I get this error:

> ERROR:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZooKeeperConnectionException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZooKeeperConnectionException:
>   org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException:
>   KeeperErrorCode = connectionLoss for
>   /hbase

I set up ssh and make sure all port are correct.

Moreover, I cannot stop hbase though `./bin/stop-hbase.sh`. I only get the follow output.

```
stopping hbase........................................................
```

Comment: But the question is your Hbase stooped? Mine is not at all stopping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pseudo-distributed means that you are running all of the processes on one machine.  You need to check that all of the required processes are running:

Hadoop:

- NameNode
- DataNode
- JobTracker
- TaskTracker

Zookeeper:

- HQuorumPeer

HBase:

- HMaster
- RegionServer

You also need to ensure that your hbase-site.xml contains the correct entries for zookeeper defining the host name and the port.  The HBase FAQ and Wiki are really quite good.  What are you missing from there?

Comment: I finally solve by using the conf from https://wiki.cloudera.com/display/DOC/HBase+Installation, please make sure that hbase.cluster.distributed is setted to true

Comment: @TerminalUser this wiki is password protected. Could you paste your conf here?

Answer (score 2):

It's because the HBase documentation has you setup your HDFS settings to point to port 8020, but the Hadoop instructions configure HDFS for port 9000.

Change hbase-site.xml settings that HBase recommends to point to port 9000 instead:

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
  <description>The directory shared by RegionServers.
  </description>
</property>
```

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04, hive(0.9.0), hbase(0.94.3), hadoop(0.20.2)-single-node, zookeeper-3.4.3, guava-11.0.2, hive-hbase-handler-0.9.0-- for hadoop,fs.default.name=hdfs://localhost:54310.which "hbase.rootdir" should I give ?either 9000 or 54310

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and got the same error message as above. In my case HMaster was not running. Using

```
sudo start-hbase.sh
```

resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

i just fixed the problem by deleting the hbase.rootdir and the hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir folders. for example:

```
more conf/hbase-site.xml
```

gives me:
    
      
        hbase.rootdir
        file:///somepath/hbase/testuser/hbase
      
      
        hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir
        /somepath/hbase/testuser/zookeeper

then remove the old data:

```
rm -fr /somepath/hbase/testuser/hbase
mkdir -p /somepath/hbase/testuser/hbase
rm -fr /somepath/hbase/testuser/zookeeper
mkdir -p /somepath/hbase/testuser/zookeeper
```

then to start it:

```
bin/start-hbase.sh
```

and finally i could connect to the local instance:

```
./bin/hbase shell
```